# iOS App - Submitting to store, validation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, validation

I am trying to submit my app to the store but upon archive validation I get this error:

```
Icon found in the Info.plist is not found under top level address wrapper
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link woz referred to seems to cover this pretty thoroughly.  The only other think I can think of to check is that the icons are included in the target.